# Mongoose: Populate path using field other than _id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

By default mongoose/mongo will populate a path using the `_id` field, and by it seems like there is no way to change the `_id` to something else.

Here are my two models which are connected with one-to-many relationship:

```js
const playlistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  externalId: String,
  title: String,
  videos: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Video',
  }],
});

const videoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  externalId: String,
  title: String,
});
```

Normally, when querying a playlist you would populate `videos` just with `.populate('videos')`, but in my case I would like to use the `externalId` field instead of the default `_id`. Is that possible?

Comment: this might help, https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3225#issuecomment-482399387, but if doesn't use $lookup aggregation

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, the way to achieve this with mongoose presently is by using [virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html#further-reading). When populating virtuals, you can specify the `localField` and `foreignField`  to whatever you want, so you are no longer bound to the default `_id` as `foreignField`. More details about this [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals).

For the scenario described in your question, you would need to add a virtual to the `playerlistSchema`, something like this:

```
playlistSchema.virtual('videoList', {
  ref: 'Video', // The model to use
  localField: 'videos', // The field in playerListSchema
  foreignField: 'externalId', // The field on videoSchema. This can be whatever you want.
});
```

Now, whenever you query for player lists, you can populate the `videoList` virtual to get the referenced video documents.

```
PlaylistModel
  .findOne({
    // ... whatever your find query needs to be
  })
  .populate('videoList')
  .exec(function (error, playList) {
    /* if a playList document is returned */
    playList.videoList; // The would be the populated array of videos
  })
```

Comment: I think it's virtual not virtuals

Answer (score 0):

2024 - Mongoose version 8

There is a better and simpler way to achieve this:

```
  PlaylistModel.find()
    .populate({
      path: 'videos',
      model: 'Video',
      select: 'title',
      foreignField: 'externalId',
    })
```

- path: specifies the field in the Announcement schema that you want to
  populate.
- model: specifies the model to use for population.
- select: specifies the fields to select from the referenced document.
- foreignField: specifies the field in the referenced model (Video in this case) that is used to match with the local field (videos in playlistSchema) for populating references. (**instead of the default `_id`**)